# UK visa required or not, for an American on a long-ish trip?

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, long-haul

I am an American trying to get a tourist visa but I am confused. The UK visa and immigration says that I do not need a visa for a 180 day (6 month) visit, but the General visa description says that I have to pay 83 pounds for the application. I don't understand what's going on and immigration services are impossible to get in contact with. Do I need to still pay for a visa when the clearly say that I do not need one? I am from the US and I am looking at the UK visa and immigration site.

Comment: OOOHH I see. That is a relief. I am glad that I do not have to wait 3 months or expedite my visa so that I can get there in time.

Answer (score 5):

As a US passport holder [you don't need a visa for the UK, unless you have a criminal record or have previously been refused entry to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism). The [General Visitor Visa page](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/overview) tells you how to apply for one if you need one. It doesn't mean everybody needs one.